# MySQL Get all users who performed same actions as current user

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have to do a query and I can't figure it out. I have an actions table ( user_id , action, created_at ), and I need to retrieve all users who performed the same actions as current_user ( in exact order).

ex.

```
current_user delete 2022/03/19 13:40
current_user add_post 2022/03/19 13:45
current_user write_comment 2022/03/22 13:48
```

Query result:

```
user_5       delete 2021/03/15 14:50
user_5       add_post 2021/05/15 13:50
user_5       write_comment 2022/06/06 14:30
user_6       delete 2021/03/15 14:50
user_6       add_post 2021/05/15 13:50
user_6       write_comment 2022/06/06 14:30
( all users with same actions )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Sounds like you should use a simple `WHERE`  clause to filter that data

Comment: @NicoHaase I can't really see how can I do this with a simple WHERE honestly, i tried using this query but I need to check all records not only prev and next : SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ( SELECT `user_id`,` action`, lag(`action`) OVER(partition by `user_id` order by `created_at` ) as prev_action,
lead(`action`) over(partition by `user_id` order by `created_at`) as next_action
from `actions` WHERE `action`="add_post" AND prev_action = "delete" AND next_action = "write_comment";

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9543e/1/0   So, i want to retrieve all users with the same actions as user 3 in exact order of actions ( based on created_at )  ( in that case user 10 )

Comment: @Abacus - Please put relevant information like that in the question, not the comments.  Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71456285/edit) link to update the question, then delete the comments.

Comment: That sqlfiddle is not opening, so those efforts have been wasted. It is far better to edit your question and include the information you would have added into sqlfiddle into your question - then we can choose how to make use of it and provide you with an answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't stipulate that the exact matching has to be in groups of 3. The following query will identify exact action sequences of 1, 2, 3 or even more then 3:

```
CREATE TABLE actions(
   user_id    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,action     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,created_at DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO actions(user_id,action,created_at)
 VALUES
  ('current_user','delete','2022/03/19 13:40')
, ('current_user','add_post','2022/03/19 13:45')
, ('current_user','write_comment','2022/03/22 13:48')

, ('other_user','delete','2022/02/19 13:40')
, ('other_user','add_post','2022/02/19 13:45')
, ('other_user','write_comment','2022/02/22 13:48')

, ('diff_user','delete','2022/02/19 12:40')
, ('diff_user','add_post','2022/02/19 12:42')
, ('diff_user','other_action','2022/02/19 12:45')
, ('diff_user','write_comment','2022/02/22 12:48')
;
```

It appears (through a comment) that you can use the `lag()` so I suggest using `row_number()` to match the action sequences of current user to other users, as follows:

```
SELECT ou.*
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at
            ) AS rn
    FROM actions
    WHERE user_id <> 'current_user'
    ) AS OU
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY created_at
            ) AS rn
    FROM actions
    WHERE user_id = 'current_user'
    ) AS CU ON ou.rn = cu.rn
    AND ou.action = cu.action
```

**result**

```
+------------+---------------+---------------------+----+
|  user_id   |    action     |     created_at      | rn |
+------------+---------------+---------------------+----+
| diff_user  | delete        | 2022-02-19 12:40:00 |  1 |
| diff_user  | add_post      | 2022-02-19 12:42:00 |  2 |
| other_user | delete        | 2022-02-19 13:40:00 |  1 |
| other_user | add_post      | 2022-02-19 13:45:00 |  2 |
| other_user | write_comment | 2022-02-22 13:48:00 |  3 |
+------------+---------------+---------------------+----+
```

Now if you really did want to limit this to sequence match of just 3, then you could subsequently `count(*) over(partition by user_id)` then filter for when that calculation is 3:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ou.*
        , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ou.user_id) AS cn
    FROM (
        SELECT *
            , row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at
                ) AS rn
        FROM actions
        WHERE user_id <> 'current_user'
        ) AS OU
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT *
            , row_number() OVER (
                ORDER BY created_at
                ) AS rn
        FROM actions
        WHERE user_id = 'current_user'
        ) AS CU ON ou.rn = cu.rn
        AND ou.action = cu.action
    ) d
WHERE cn = 3
```

**result**

```
+------------+---------------+---------------------+----+----+
|  user_id   |    action     |     created_at      | rn | cn |
+------------+---------------+---------------------+----+----+
| other_user | write_comment | 2022-02-22 13:48:00 |  1 |  3 |
| other_user | add_post      | 2022-02-19 13:45:00 |  2 |  3 |
| other_user | delete        | 2022-02-19 13:40:00 |  3 |  3 |
+------------+---------------+---------------------+----+----+
```

for reference *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=73d5a7bfa7de92507f1758c858637970)* (nb: using postgres as MySQL 8 wasn't available at the time)

**btw:** you probably also need to introduce the concept of "session" into this logic but that is left for you to consider.